# Using Inject and AssistedInject together

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm writing an app using Dagger-Hilt for dependency injection. In my viewmodel, I already have an @Inject for the repo. Now, I want to add an @AssistedInject for the savestatehandle, but I keep getting an error if I use either one of them or use both of them together.

Is there a way I can use them both together? Thank you

```
@HiltViewModel
class DaoViewModel @Inject @AssistedInject constructor(private val repository: MoviesFavoritesRepository,
                                                       @Assisted private val state: SavedStateHandle) :
    ViewModel() {
```

Comment: You don't need to use @Assisted with `SavedStateHandle`, remove `@AssistedInject` and `@Assisted` and it should work https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodels, https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html

Answer (score 0):

You'd only use @AssistedInject.  Because you can't inject something that requires an assistance, you don't have all the data ready. If you did, there'd be no reason to use an assisted inject.

Comment: I tried that and it tells me this "  ViewModel constructor should be annotated with @ Inject instead of @AssistedInject. "

Comment: Most likely you're using it elsewhere in a way that would require it to be injected.  Which means your injection is set up wrong in multiple places, or you need to not be injecting somewhere.  Injection isn't usable for all scenarios.

Comment: But the app was working fine before I implemented savedstatehandle so it can't be it

Comment: @Ahmadddd4 Sure it could.  If DaoViewModel is injected into something else in an unassisted manor, then you can't use assisted injection on one of its parameters.  And you just added an assisted parameter when it previously had none.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Dagger 2.49](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.49), assisted injection is properly supported in Hilt: https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model#assisted-injection

This is how your ViewModel should look like:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel(assistedFactory = MyViewModel.Factory::class)
class MyViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
  @Assisted val runtimeArg: String,
  private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
  private val someDependency: SomeDependency,
) : ViewModel() {
  @AssistedFactory interface Factory {
    fun create(runtimeArg: String): MyViewModel
  }
  ...
}
```

And this is how you can create it:

```kotlin
private val myViewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>(
  extrasProducer = {
    defaultViewModelCreationExtras.withCreationCallback<MyViewModel.Factory> { factory -> 
      factory.create(runtimeArg = "abc")  
    }
  }
)

// or in Compose:
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel, MyViewModel.Factory>(
  creationCallback = { factory -> factory.create(runtimeArg = "abc") }
)
```

In the case of `SavedStateHandle`, it can actually be added as a non-assisted dependency as in the example above since it's a binding from `ViewModelComponent`. So if all you need is to have the `SavedStateHandle` there, you don't need anything more than this:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {
  ...
}
```

And you can create it as any other ViewModel:

```kotlin
private val myViewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()
```